# Is it viable to do video streaming via pipe in windows?

Tags: c++, video-streaming, pipe

Is the pipe efficient enough to continuously pass video streams to other applications?

If yes,can you provide a sample code in c/c++?

Comment: Why do you need that? Why not to use sockets?

Comment: It's said they two basically the same,but pipe more efficient. But I'm stuck by the sending/receiving logic seriously:(

Comment: How can you get stuck?  For the sender/producer, it's just like writing to a file; for the receiver/consumer, it's just like reading from a file.  In fact, if you're launching the two from the command line, using your shell/command-prompt to create the pipe, then your apps can simply write to stdout and read from stdin.  Maybe you should get comfortable with that first.  Whether it's video data or not is irrelevant to the data sending/receipt, but obvious indicative of required transmission speed (if real time) - pipes are fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at these examples:

- [Named pipe server using overlapped I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365603(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [Named pipe client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365592(v=VS.85).aspx)